# Пути к фоновому изображению не соответствуют написаному в CSS

Tags: css

У меня у шапки есть фоновое изображение, пути прописаны верно, файл подключен тоже правильно. Но когда открываю страничку, через инспектор видно что пути не те которые я задавал изначально, при этом у меня в sublime в конце js скрипт, для автоматического обновления при сохранении файла. Так вот, сохраняю index.php (даже если ничего не менял, просто обновляю страничку), путь неверный, сохраняю header-style.css, магическим образом пути становятся верными, и фон отображается корректно. Но при обычном обновлении странички, опять же пути сбиваются...

P.s.: до этого был путь к изображению "../images/header-bg.png", потом переместил в папку и соответственно изменил путь на "../images/background/header-bg.png", но ищет по первому пути

Comment: Кеш сбрасываете? (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: Тогда не сбросил. Действительно из-за кеша была проблема. Уже все нормально отображается

Comment: Если что - `Ctrl+Shift+R` - это хард решреш страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было просто сбросить кеш и обновить страничку... (Ctrl + F5)